# Splitting string with strtok in C

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I can't figure out why the second while loop is not executing. It has an access violation on result[count] = atoi... I thought adding the strcpy would help because I realized the original string was being modified, but it made no difference. Also, I am using C++ actually, but most of the source is in C where speed is necessary.

```
int* split(const char* str, const char* delim)
{
    char* tok;
    int* result;
    int count = 0;

    char* oldstr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(str));
    strcpy(oldstr, str);

    tok = strtok((char*)str, delim);
    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    result = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);

    count = 0;
    tok = strtok((char*)oldstr, delim);
    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        result[count] = atoi(tok);
        count++;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: there is no need to cast from `malloc()`

Comment: If speed is so important, you should find a solution which doesn't scan every input character three times. (Or four with the strcpy.) You may well find it easier to write an efficient solution in C++.

Comment: I actually had done it in C++ originally and switched to C because I thought it would be faster, and it does seem to be. When this code executes it seems to be about the same speed (not a problem), but the rendering runs about 1/4 faster because it uses C arrays instead of vectors. Not sure if this could be done in C++ without vectors. If it could, that's probably the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    char* oldstr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(str));
    strcpy(oldstr, str);
```

You don't allocate enough space. Since `str` is a `char *`, you are allocating however many bytes a `char *` takes on your platform, which is probably not enough to hold a string. You want:

```
    char* oldstr = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    strcpy(oldstr, str);
```

Or, for simplicity:

```
    char* oldstr = strdup(str);
```